# Letter in Appendix missing in XePersian

Tags: sectioning, xepersian

The following example shows that there is the letter "A." missing in the caption of the appendix in the pdf when xepersian is used. Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\usepackage{scrpage2}

\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont{XB Niloofar} 


\begin{document}
\begin{latin}


\frontmatter

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chapter*{Preface}


We thank for discussion.

\newpage

We thank the \LaTeX{} developers for support.

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter Title}

Some text.

\newpage

Even more text.

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}

This is an appendix.

\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a bug report in https://github.com/vafa/xepersian/issues but I do not promise updating xepersian package unless there is some donations to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `xepersian` (via `scrbook-xepersian.def`) redefines `\appendix` so that it contains the declaration

```
\gdef\thechapter{\@harfi\c@chapter}
```

However, in the `latin` environment the default Roman font is used (in your example it's Latin Modern), which might not have the characters used by the harfi numerals (whatever they be). Indeed in the log file you find the lines

```
Appendix آ<U+200D>.
Missing character: There is no آ in font [lmsans10-bold]:mapping=tex-text!
Missing character: There is no <U+200D> in font [lmsans10-bold]:mapping=tex-text!
```

(U+200D is ZERO WIDTH JOINER)

For completeness, here's the replacement text of `\@harfi`

```
\@harfi=macro:
#1->\ifcase #1\or آ\or ب\or پ\or ت\or ث\or ج\or چ\or ح\or خ\or د\or
 ذ\or ر\or ز\or ژ\or س\or ش\or ص\or ض\or ط\or ظ\or ع\or غ\or ف\or
 ق\or ک\or گ\or ل\or م\or ن\or و\or ه\or ی\else \@ctrerr \fi
```

### Solution

You get your letter back by saying

```
\appendix
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
```